# Value is zero after filter SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I`m new in C#..

I have write function to filter **department.** And this function will return **idDepartment**.

**New problem is**, department keep value "**System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text : ADMIN** ", that`s why i got zero. So how can i take "ADMIN" only and keep to department?

Update :

```
    public partial class frmEditStaff : Form
{

    private string connString;
    private string userId, department;  //Department parameter coming from here
    private string conString = "Datasource";


    public frmEditStaff(string strUserID, string strPosition)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Pass value from frmListStaff to userID text box

        tbStaffId.Text = strUserID.ToString();
        userId = strUserID.ToString();
        department = strPosition.ToString();


    }
```

This code below is working, don`t have any problem.

```
public int lookUpDepart()
        {
            int idDepart=0;

            using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                string lookUpDepartmenId = "SELECT idDepartment FROM tbl_department WHERE department = '" + department + "';";
                openCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand querylookUpDepartmenId = new SqlCommand(lookUpDepartmenId, openCon))
                {
                    SqlDataReader read = querylookUpDepartmenId.ExecuteReader();

                    while (read.Read())
                    {
                        idDepart = int.Parse(read[0].ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                openCon.Close();
                return idDepart;
            }


        }
```

Thanks for help. Happy nice day!

Comment: Where is this department  parameter coming from?

Comment: Run your query manually to see if it returns result because if not your loop simply won't be executed this means that your local variable won't change and 0 will be returned.

Comment: Apart from the string concatenation your code seems formally correct. Are you sure there is a department corrisponding to your query value?

Comment: Please check if your table row for 'department'value has the idDepartment value ZERO.

Comment: Do you try it manually ? Perhaps your query does not return a row.

Comment: use [Parameters](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx&ei=JcBFULvyNOeK4gTK7oCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHLwGkRVRodFZVT4ffztc5FMPlDqg&sig2=tOrW8o520hVXwXRk5QwCwQ) and **never** strings.

Comment: Side note: idDepartment is probably int already; there is no need to convert it to string and then back to int. Use cast: `idDepart = (int) read[0];`

Comment: @SonalSatpute Is he putting the idDepartment in the where condition?

Comment: Well does it hit the breakpoint at `read.Read()`, it seems there is no record found and its returning the initialized value of `idDepart`

Comment: Check the value of your "department" variable if it is really passing the right value. Do this query in your database to see if it really returns something

SELECT idDepartment FROM tbl_department WHERE department ='myDepartmentValue'

Comment: @Carls Jr: he is trying to read the "idDepartment" as "read[0]"

Comment: You can also to use `read["idDepartment"]`. Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Hello all. I have try run query manually, then result is ok. The problem is parameter. I take parameter is from another form. So when i try show message box, Is show "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text : ADMIN ". How i can solve this problem?

Comment: If strPosition is actually a label try `department = strPosition.Text`.

Comment: Hello, I tried it department = strPosition.Text; , but error.. Hehe, thanks for help...;)

Comment: What do you write in MessageBox? And do not use .ToString() everywhere, strUserID and strPosition are already strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your problem : department keep value "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text : ADMIN "

**You have problem right in this call** `frmEditStaff(strUserID,yourLabel.ToString());`

Although you have not shared your call for this function/Constructor, yet it seems your second parameter is going wrong in this call. Do not use `ToString()` here. Rather you have to use `.Text` as

`frmEditStaff(strUserID,yourLabel.Text);`

That will solve your problem. I knew it because usually programmers have experience of making this mistake :)

Comment: Thanks for help.. Work perfectly... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int lookUpDepart()
{
    int idDepart = 0;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        string lookUpDepartmenId = "SELECT idDepartment FROM tbl_department WHERE department = " + department;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand querylookUpDepartmenId = new SqlCommand(lookUpDepartmenId, openCon))
        {
            SqlDataReader read = querylookUpDepartmenId.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                idDepart = Convert.ToInt32((read[0]).ToString());
                break;
            }
        }

        con.Close();

        return idDepart;
    }
}
```

Try the above code, I reworked it. It is working for me...

Comment: How can read[0][0] work? read contains single row after read.Read() and only takes columnIndex. Please del it to avoid negative votes (by others, not by me because i prefer to guide through comments rather than down-voting it especially for new comers). Question is little more correct than the answer :(

Comment: Anyway @DineshGuptha : Thanks for help me....:) I have update new problem above. If don`t mine you can look.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a single value from a single row, you can use the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method, that does all that for you, like this:

```
using (SqlCommand querylookUpDepartmenId = new SqlCommand(lookUpDepartmenId, openCon))
{
   idDepart = int.Parse(querylookUpDepartmenId.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

And again, using string concatenation in SQL queries is [just plain wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

---

And for your updated question: Try using the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx) property of the label, insead of the .ToString() method.

I would recommend getting a [good tutorial book about C# / .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-sharp-net-books), and following the examples there.

Comment: Thanks for help Sweko!, i have update a new problem... Hope can help me to solve...:)